# Javascript : find first unchecked box and retrieve information from row

Tags: javascript, checkbox, row

So I am trying to find a way to extract data from the first row where the checkbox from the first column is unchecked. I know this may sound like a true beginner question but I couldn't manage to find how to do it despite searching for quite a few hours.

Here a step-by-step of my goal to clarify :

1. Find the first checkbox which is unchecked;
2. Retrieve information from another column (inner html) but from the corresponding row **and** an attribute ("name") of the checkbox;
3. Without opening it on-screen, use the attribute of the checkbox (partial URL) to open completed URL and retrieve more information into MySQL;
4. Check the checkbox;
5. Rince and repeat

I am only looking for info concerning step one and two, the rest is there for clarification. I do not have prior experience in Javascript writing prior my last few days of Internet browsing, the only coding I've done were statistical analysis in R.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Nikola

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can use the same class for every checkbox (i.e. rowcheck):

```
<input type="checkbox" class="rowcheck" id="CbRow_1" name="test" value="test">
```

And then you loop through the checkboxes:

```
$(".rowcheck").each(function (index, element) {
        if ($(element).prop("checked")) {
            //Get the row number from ID
            var rownumber = $(element).prop("id").split("_")[1];
            //Now you do stuff with the other element
            $("#element_" + rownumber).html("whatever")
        }
    });
```

Comment: I cannot modify the html I am working with, but the checkboxes don't have a class. Is there a way around? They only have 2 attributes, each has a unique 'name' and they share the type obviously. If we could search by type it would be find they are the only CBs on the window. 



`$('.checkbox').each(function (index, element) {
  if ($(element).prop('checked')) {
    var rownumber = $(element).prop('id').split('_') [1];
    var report = [
      $('#report_list' + rownumber).getElementByAttribute('name')
    ]
  }
});`

Comment: Tried a few variants also, can't get any to work. They show no error but variables are undefined. In your example you use an id which holds the rownumber, I do not have they row number anywhere on the DOMs, except counting tr's

Comment: you can iterate over any element, you only need a proper selector matching your requirements: